# Obtain Real-Time video statistics

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

I'm attempting to obtain real-time video statistics. Why? The files I have are recorded using a streaming format, they are not indexed, most of the meta data is either missing or not as precise as I'd like.

Essentially, I'm looking for a tool/means that scans a video file, and based on the actual frames it is receiving, determines a bitrate, framerate, length, and any other useful information.

Comment: You know `ffmpeg -i yourvideo`, do you?

Comment: @dessert that uses statistics from the video meta-data/tags

Comment: Update. My understanding of video containers was incredibly flawed when this question was asked. The concept of realtime statistics does not apply to anything but actual streaming. The containers  that i was using (avi) only has a fixed FPS

Comment: Please [edit] your question and update it accordingly. Especially as there’s no answer yet it’s not at all a problem to change title and text even radically if necessary, the post history preserves previous states.